# R is using all values of a column as parameters

Tags: r, parameters

I'm trying to run a regression with two different data sets (that have the same headers/parameters). One of the results has no problem. However, the other one uses all of the values in one of my parameters (Height) as parameters, as shown in the following image.

[image]

How do I fix it so that it looks like the first one (as in the image below)?

[image]

Comment: It helps if you provide a dataset that reproduces your problem. It's possible that `Dist` is stored as a `factor` object in the first dataset (confirm with `str(x)`, where `x` is the name of your first dataset).

Comment: Figured it out - problems in my data set. The numbers in the faulty Dist didn't reach all the way down in the excel columns.